# citybikes: JSON to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, csv

I am using python-citybikes (https://pypi.org/project/python-citybikes/) to retrieve some data. 
However, I can't figure out a way export the data

```
import citybikes
import pandas as pd
client = citybikes.Client()
GlasgowNextBike = citybikes.Network(client, uid='nextbike-glasgow')
list(GlasgowNextBike.stations)
Stations = list(GlasgowNextBike.stations)
 pd.read_json(Stations)
```

I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-5a1904def0e8>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_json(Stations)

  File "/Users/noor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/noor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 585, in read_json
    path_or_buf, encoding=encoding, compression=compression

  File "/Users/noor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 200, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

My question is :

How can I export/save the results as JSON or CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage) module, like so:

```
import citybikes, json

client = citybikes.Client()
GlasgowNextBike = citybikes.Network(client, uid='nextbike-glasgow')

with open('GlasgowNextBike.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(GlasgowNextBike.data, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: I am getting error Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: You need to copy the entire traceback, like you did in your question. That just tells me there is an error. It's not actually the error or type of error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-87-f2ac51f900a4>", line 2, in <module>
    json.dump(GlasgowNextBike, f, indent=2)

  File "/Users/noor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:

  File "/Users/noor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)

  File "/Users/noor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

TypeError: Object of type Network is not JSON serializable

Comment: I made a mistake in my original answer. It works now.